# How to convert video(stored in S3) to image and upload it back to S3 bucket?

Tags: java, node.js, amazon-s3, lambda, ffmpeg

I am trying to perform below steps:

- Read video from S3 bucket
- Convert Video into images
- and upload images to S3 back

I don't want to use any Local file system or don't want to store video/image in local disk.

Running the code as an AWS Lambda function.

In Java,
How can we upload an image directly to S3 after framing a video?

In Node,
Can we pass s3 url to **ffmpeg** either to command line utility or a code module?

Sharing some sample code which I am using to read video from S3:

```
        String bucketName = "ibis-static";
        ObjectListing objectListing = s3.listObjects(new ListObjectsRequest()
                .withBucketName(bucketName));
        String key_url = "https://s3.amazonaws.com/";
        for (S3ObjectSummary objectSummary : objectListing.getObjectSummaries()) {
            S3Object object = s3.getObject(bucketName, objectSummary.getKey()); 

            if(object.getKey().startsWith("videos/")){
                key_url = key_url + bucketName + "/" + object.getKey();
                logger.log("Passing object to Computer Vision");
                logger.log("\n" + object.getObjectContent().read()); //returning 0
                logger.log("\n" + new URL(key_url).openStream().read()); //returning 0
                //cvm.getImageDetails(logger, object, bucketName, object.getKey());
            }
            object.close();
        }
```

Comment: Isn't the official AWS SDK documentation helping? S3 upload example with Java: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UploadObjSingleOpJava.html , and it seems `putObject` can receive `InputStream` too (so you don't need files): http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/AmazonS3Client.html#putObject-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-java.io.InputStream-com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.ObjectMetadata-

Comment: I am using the same to upload an image to S3. But those images are not in proper format if I pass those to AWS Rekognition then giving me **Image format exception**.
That means the issue is when converting video to Frames and converting it to bytebuffer.

Can you please help me with that?